# Can't exit buffer using leader mapping - 'cannot make changes'

Tags: buffers, error, map-operator

I have a leader key set up, and a mapping that allows me to exit windows without typing `:`:

```
let mapleader = 'f'
map <leader>q = :q<CR>
```

Today I installed `MattesGroeger/vim-bookmarks` using Vundle, and everything went fine. However when I view the annotations list using `ma`, and then I try to exit it using `fq`, vim spits out this error phrase:

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

But I can exit it just fine if I manually type out `:q`

The other answers I've seen so far regarding the `modifiable`/`nonmodifiable` attributes of buffers imply that a solution is to set the buffer as modifiable, however that seems like a hack. It looks like `map` and friends are restricted in use in buffers without `modifiable` set, so is there a specific kind of `map` that will allow me to use this mapping across all buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `=` in your command. It's being taken as part of the expansion for the mapping.

That's triggering [the `=` command](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3D), which typically reformats a block of code. Since you have a space after the `=`, that's being swallowed as the "motion" for `=` (which is roughly equivalent to the motion of going right one character.)

I guess this reformatting wasn't doing anything on your regular buffers, so it wasn't leaving your buffer in a modified state, which would have interfered with the second part of the command.

But with a read-only buffer, that's likely to be a problem, since the command will fail early, in the way you experienced.

To fix it:

```
map <leader>q :q<CR>
```

But you might also want to make this mapping non-recursive (usually a best practice) and probably only allow it in normal mode (and not visual or select modes):

```
nnoremap <leader>q :q<CR>
```

Comment: Oh!!! Yes you're right! I don't know how that slipped in because my initial mappings file just didn't have it, and my brain just filtered it out for some reason :) Thank you!